# vhosts only shows one root for all domains

Tags: xampp, mamp, apache, hosts

I am using MAMP. I want separate domains to use different roots on my local computer.

- I want "localhost" to go to my htdocs folder.
- I want "wowzers.loc" to use /Donald/Projects/wowzers as its root.
- I want "secondsite.loc" to use /Donald/Projects/secondsite as its
  root.

Here is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/donald/Projects/wowzers"
  ServerName wowzers.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/donald/Projects/secondsite"
  ServerName secondsite.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

Right now, typing "localhost", "wowzers.loc", or "secondsite.loc" will all navigate to the first entry in my vhosts file. In this example, everything navigates to "wowzers.loc".

Why do all my servernames point to the top entry?

Comment: Did you try to set virualHost for localhost just like other?

Comment: Neo, can you be more specific? What "other" are you referring to? Which VirtualHost are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it without the quotes around `DocumentRoot` and also pass the same argument from `NameVirtualHost` to  `VirtualHost` i.e.: `<VirtualHost *:80>`

[Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)